# Adaptive layout of the website

Tags: html, css

I apologize in advance for my bad English, if what not so)).

Hello, I need help, how to move the blocks down when scaled for the phone.

At the moment, they are just slightly narrowed if you reduce the screen.

Here is an [example](https://rusability.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/adaptivnyiy-veb-dizayn.png) of how they should be migrated when scaling.

Help please thank you in advance.

Here is the block layout code for the site:

```css
.section {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
    will-change: transform;
    -webkit-transition-property: all;
    transition-property: all;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 300ms;
            transition-duration: 300ms;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
            transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  }
  .section:first-child {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #F06060;
  }
  .section:nth-child(2) {
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    background: #FA987D;
  }
  .section:nth-child(3) {
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    background: #72CCA7;
  }
  .section:nth-child(4) {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    background: #10A296;
  }
  .section.is-expanded {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .has-expanded-item .section:not(.is-expanded) {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
            transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  .section.is-expanded {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms linear 300ms;
    transition: opacity 200ms linear 300ms;
  }
  .demo-box {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 300;
  }
```

```html
<main class="main">
  <section class="section">
    <div class="demo-box">Section 1</div>
  </section>
  <section class="section">
    <div class="demo-box">Section 2</div>
  </section>
  <section class="section">
    <div class="demo-box">Section 3</div>
  </section>
  <section class="section">
    <div class="demo-box">Section 4</div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Use Bootstrap Grid system Follow this link
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_templates.asp

Comment: Have you tried using @media queries? I suggest you to read about them and try solve it yourself first . Then if you’ll stuck at some point - post a question again with specific problem . Current question shows no effort of solving it yourself and therefore it should be closed.

Comment: @Shaik I don't want to use bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (max-width:480)
{  
   .section {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
        float:left;
    }
}
```

try This i think it is useful

Comment: It will not solve his problem . Try it yourself in fiddle. Section has absolute position , you will not affect it with float:left.